# .frame(maxWidth: .infinity does not streatch over all width, why?

Tags: swiftui

[image]

Right Top navbar is forced to use all width, but not happens:

```swift
HStack {
   content
}.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
```

Left uses 300

```swift
MenuView().frame(minWidth: 300, maxWidth: 300)
```

Why content of the Navbar does not uses all the width?

```
Button(action: {
    // handle button tap
}) {
    Text("Create Type Tree")
}.padding()
Spacer()
Button(action: {
    self.showDocumentPicker.toggle()
}) {
    Text("Load Type Tree")
}
```

My assumption was `Spacer()` will take up all possible space.

This phenomenon happens only on newest generation iPad.